# iPad 4.2 crash launch

Tags: objective-c, ipad, cocos2d-iphone

Sad, sad girl needs your help=) I'm creating app to iPad. Apple send log crash that app crash launch with iPad 4.2. Can someone help how can I read this log crash?? I don't understand what is the matter with app, because previous version at iPad don't crash. That line CCDirector.m:116 is `CC_DIRECTOR_INIT();`

```
Exception Type: EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)

Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000

Crashed Thread: 0

Thread 0 Crashed:

0 libSystem.B.dylib 0x361672d4 0x360ee000 + 496340

1 libSystem.B.dylib 0x361672c4 0x360ee000 + 496324

2 libSystem.B.dylib 0x361672b6 0x360ee000 + 496310

3 libSystem.B.dylib 0x3617bd72 0x360ee000 + 580978

4 libstdc++.6.dylib 0x314e9a20 0x314a5000 + 281120

5 libobjc.A.dylib 0x31acb594 0x31ac5000 + 26004

6 libstdc++.6.dylib 0x314e7df2 0x314a5000 + 273906

7 libstdc++.6.dylib 0x314e7e46 0x314a5000 + 273990

8 libstdc++.6.dylib 0x314e7f16 0x314a5000 + 274198

9 libobjc.A.dylib 0x31aca4c4 0x31ac5000 + 21700

10 CoreFoundation 0x3284b7c2 0x327ab000 + 657346

11 Foundation 0x3212f298 0x320dd000 + 336536

12 App_name 0x00026ee4 +[CCDirector setDirectorType:] (CCDirector.m:116)

13 App_name 0x0000335c -[App_name_AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:] 
(App_name_AppDelegate.m:41)

14 UIKit 0x32c19bfa 0x32bdd000 + 248826

15 UIKit 0x32c15252 0x32bdd000 + 229970

16 UIKit 0x32be1484 0x32bdd000 + 17540

17 UIKit 0x32be0ec2 0x32bdd000 + 16066

18 UIKit 0x32be0900 0x32bdd000 + 14592

19 GraphicsServices 0x3094aefc 0x30946000 + 20220

20 CoreFoundation 0x327e06f8 0x327ab000 + 218872

21 CoreFoundation 0x327e06bc 0x327ab000 + 218812

22 CoreFoundation 0x327d2f76 0x327ab000 + 163702

23 CoreFoundation 0x327d2c80 0x327ab000 + 162944

24 CoreFoundation 0x327d2b88 0x327ab000 + 162696

25 UIKit 0x32c14302 0x32bdd000 + 226050

26 UIKit 0x32c11e8c 0x32bdd000 + 216716

27 App_name 0x00002f50 main (main.m:13)

28 App_name 0x00002f28 start + 32

Thread 1:

0 libSystem.B.dylib 0x3611b974 0x360ee000 + 186740

1 libSystem.B.dylib 0x361c5704 0x360ee000 + 882436

2 libSystem.B.dylib 0x361c5174 0x360ee000 + 881012

3 libSystem.B.dylib 0x361c4b98 0x360ee000 + 879512

4 libSystem.B.dylib 0x3616924a 0x360ee000 + 504394

5 libSystem.B.dylib 0x36161970 0x360ee000 + 473456


Thread 2:

0 libSystem.B.dylib 0x361699e0 0x360ee000 + 506336

1 libSystem.B.dylib 0x36169364 0x360ee000 + 504676

2 libSystem.B.dylib 0x36161970 0x360ee000 + 473456


Thread 3:

0 libSystem.B.dylib 0x360ef268 0x360ee000 + 4712

1 libSystem.B.dylib 0x360f1354 0x360ee000 + 13140

2 CoreFoundation 0x327d3648 0x327ab000 + 165448

3 CoreFoundation 0x327d2ed2 0x327ab000 + 163538

4 CoreFoundation 0x327d2c80 0x327ab000 + 162944

5 CoreFoundation 0x327d2b88 0x327ab000 + 162696

6 WebCore 0x30e54124 0x30d9d000 + 749860

7 libSystem.B.dylib 0x36168886 0x360ee000 + 501894

8 libSystem.B.dylib 0x3615da88 0x360ee000 + 457352


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:

r0: 0x00000000 r1: 0x00000000 r2: 0x00000001 r3: 0x3ec0f2e8

r4: 0x00000006 r5: 0x314e7989 r6: 0x0022f24c r7: 0x2fdfe1d0

r8: 0x00073592 r9: 0x00000065 r10: 0x0009f3ec r11: 0x00000000

ip: 0x00000025 sp: 0x2fdfe1d0 lr: 0x361672cb pc: 0x361672d4

cpsr: 0x00000010
```

Comment: Your application called abort() meaning you probably have an unhandled exception somewhere. Run the app on the 4.2 simulator and see if you get an exception.

Comment: Please show the code for the method `-[App_name_AppDelegate applicationDidFinishLaunching:]` in `App_name_AppDelegate.m`.

Comment: Never mind, I solve that problem=) Thank's anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the applicationDidFinishLaunching -method. Is that 4.2 simulator all ready available to xcode?

- (void) applicationDidFinishLaunching:(UIApplication*)application
  {
  [application setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];

  self.notifyCenter=[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

  [notifyCenter addObserver:self selector:@selector(trackNotifications:) name:nil object:nil];

  // Tell the UIDevice to send notifications when the orientation changes

  // CC_DIRECTOR_INIT()
  //
  // 1. Initializes an EAGLView with 0-bit depth format, and RGB565 render buffer
  // 2. EAGLView multiple touches: disabled
  // 3. creates a UIWindow, and assign it to the "window" var (it must already be declared)
  // 4. Parents EAGLView to the newly created window
  // 5. Creates Display Link Director
  // 5a. If it fails, it will use an NSTimer director
  // 6. It will try to run at 60 FPS
  // 7. Display FPS: NO
  // 8. Device orientation: Portrait
  // 9. Connects the director to the EAGLView
  //

  CC_DIRECTOR_INIT();

  [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:@"UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification" object:nil];

  ```
  // Obtain the shared director in order to...
  ```

  CCDirector *director = [CCDirector sharedDirector];

  // Sets landscape mode

  [director setDeviceOrientation:kCCDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft];

  // Turn on display FPS

  [director setDisplayFPS:NO];

  // Turn on multiple touches

  EAGLView *view = [director openGLView];

  [view setMultipleTouchEnabled:YES];

  // Default texture format for PNG/BMP/TIFF/JPEG/GIF images
  // It can be RGBA8888, RGBA4444, RGB5_A1, RGB565
  // You can change anytime.

  [CCTexture2D setDefaultAlphaPixelFormat:kTexture2DPixelFormat_RGBA8888];

  state=1;

  state2=1;

  Start *start=[Start node];

  [[CCDirector sharedDirector] runWithScene: start];

}